# Reorganize Dictionary

Tags: python, csv, reorganize

I have a .csv file that I've read into python using csv.dictwriter that looks something like this:

```
[
    {'id':'1', 'date':'12312004','var1':'234', 'var2':'456'},
    {'id':'1', 'date':'12312005','var1':'200', 'var2':'466'},
    {'id':'1', 'date':'12312006','var1':'760', 'var2':'656'},
    {'id':'1', 'date':'12312007','var1':'215', 'var2':'256'},
    {'id':'2', 'date':'5312006','var1':'234', 'var2':'456'},
    {'id':'2', 'date':'5312007','var1':'200', 'var2':'466'},
    {'id':'2', 'date':'5312008','var1':'760', 'var2':'656'},
    {'id':'2', 'date':'5312009','var1':'215', 'var2':'256'},
]
```

I'd like to reorganize it to:

```
{'1': {
    '12312004': {'var1': '234', 'var2': '456'},
    '12312005': {'var1': '200', 'var2': '466'},
    '12312006': {'var1': '760', 'var2': '656'},
    '12312007': {'var1': '215', 'var2': '256'}},
 '2': {
     '5312006': {'var1': '234', 'var2': '456'},
     '5312007': {'var1': '200', 'var2': '466'},
     '5312008': {'var1': '760', 'var2': '656'},
     '5312009': {'var1': '215', 'var2': '256'}}
}
```

Comment: Neither input nor desired output are valid Python. Can you please use ASCII quotes (`'` or `"`) and make it clear what type of object your input is (is it a list perhaps?).

Comment: Sorry.  I wrote this in a text editor and it didn't past well.  Thanks for fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided your input is a list, you can do this:

```
output = {}
for entry in input_list:
    entry = entry.copy()  # so we can mangle it
    id = entry.pop('id')
    date = entry.pop('date')
    output.setdefault(id, {})[date] = entry
```

The `dict.setdefault()` call returns the value for the key `id`, but if there is no such key, the second argument will be added to the `output` dictionary for that key and returned instead.

Demo:

```
>>> input_list = [
...     {'id':'1', 'date':'12312004','var1':'234', 'var2':'456'},
...     {'id':'1', 'date':'12312005','var1':'200', 'var2':'466'},
...     {'id':'1', 'date':'12312006','var1':'760', 'var2':'656'},
...     {'id':'1', 'date':'12312007','var1':'215', 'var2':'256'},
...     {'id':'2', 'date':'5312006','var1':'234', 'var2':'456'},
...     {'id':'2', 'date':'5312007','var1':'200', 'var2':'466'},
...     {'id':'2', 'date':'5312008','var1':'760', 'var2':'656'},
...     {'id':'2', 'date':'5312009','var1':'215', 'var2':'256'},
... ]
>>> output = {}
>>> for entry in input_list:
...     entry = entry.copy()  # so we can alter it
...     id = entry.pop('id')
...     date = entry.pop('date')
...     output.setdefault(id, {})[date] = entry
... 
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(output)
{'1': {'12312004': {'var1': '234', 'var2': '456'},
       '12312005': {'var1': '200', 'var2': '466'},
       '12312006': {'var1': '760', 'var2': '656'},
       '12312007': {'var1': '215', 'var2': '256'}},
 '2': {'5312006': {'var1': '234', 'var2': '456'},
       '5312007': {'var1': '200', 'var2': '466'},
       '5312008': {'var1': '760', 'var2': '656'},
       '5312009': {'var1': '215', 'var2': '256'}}}
```